# Malloc-Dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management

Code:

```
int *a;
char *b;
float *c;
short*d;
a = malloc(10* sizeof(int)); 
b = malloc(10 * sizeof(char)); 
c = malloc(16 * sizeof(float));
d = malloc(32 * sizeof(short));
printf("\n a:%d b:%d c:%d d:%d", a, b, c, d);
```

When i execute the programm, i can understand that each malloc differs from one another some bytes(when allocated in memory). Can anyone explain why this happens?
For example the first and second malloc differ 80 bytes. The second and the thrid differ 24 bytes. Why this is happening?

Comment: `%d` is the wrong format for a pointer. `%d` takes an `int`. To print a pointer, you need `printf("%p", (void *)ptr)`.

Comment: The pointers are different because you can't store multiple values in the same memory location.

Comment: neither what you are printing is clear, nor your question. you are just printing a random values, your intention is not clear.

Comment: Yes, i can understand what you are saying, but my question is why 80 and 24 bytes? I see that both 80 and 24 are divided exactly by 4. So why not 35 bytes?

Comment: Why don't you print out `10* sizeof(int)`?

Comment: this will not answer your question, but in general things are aligned at 4 byte boundaries (DWORD) in memory for easy access and speed. unlike in files they are aligned at cluster size.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that multiple `malloc`'d objects will be contiguous in memory; depending on how fragmented your heap is, how your heap manager does its internal bookkeeping, whether it uses a "first fit" or "best fit" algorithm, alignment requirements, etc., two successively allocated objects may be nowhere near each other.

Answer (score 0):

The values returned by `malloc` are unspecified; they depend on the particular `malloc` implementation.

Some simple implementations use linked list, some more advanced use buckets of various sizes, some round up to the nearest multiple of some size.

So you cannot depend on any particular "difference" between two successive `malloc` return values. And why would you?

Note first that best practice for mallocing arrays is to multiply the element count by what the pointer points to, i.e.

```
a = malloc(10 * sizeof *a); 
b = malloc(10 * sizeof *b); 
c = malloc(16 * sizeof *c);
d = malloc(32 * sizeof *d);
```

This way you can change the type without touching the `malloc` arguments.

Note second, the printf format specifier for a pointer is `%p` and the argument must be cast to `(void *)` (unless it already is a ptr-to-void).